# How to compile a standalone exe with visual studio 2019 [C++] [SFML]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, sfml

I have a project that uses SFML library, I would like to create an independent .exe file, i.e. I don't need to send any files other than .exe to share it to other user. The questions that I have seen on the subject are quite old.
Of course I use c++

Comment: This may  help: [https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link-static](https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#build-link-static) if you don't want to create and use an installer that installs your application and required dlls on the target system.

Comment: Adding to @drescherjm 's comment. Even if you do link your library statically you need to export your assets as well (textures, audio files, etc.), which clearly can't be packaged with just an executable file. A better way would be to just create an installer.